# Mark igraph communities in dendPlot

Tags: r, plot, social-networking, igraph, dendrogram

I'm trying to plot a dendrogram of a community that was detected using fastgreedy.community, but I would like to have the branches labeled with the community number they correspond to.

Is there any way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this post. It seems to have everything that you would want. Hope it helps.

[Creating a legend for a dendrogram with coloured leaves in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967880/creating-a-legend-for-a-dendrogram-with-coloured-leaves-in-r)